# How to change author delimeter in BibTex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have APA style BibTex code. The authors name is separated with 'and' in the references. However, I want to change 'and' to the ',' (comma). I checked some solutions online but none of them couldn't help me.

For example I have this reference:

"Benbir, G. and Korkmaz, B., 2014. Lizensefali ve otizm: olgu sunumu, **Cerrahpaşa tıp dergisi**, **36**(1):49 – 54."

I need to it in the style of below:

"Benbir, G., Korkmaz, B., 2014. Lizensefali ve otizm: olgu sunumu, **Cerrahpasa tıp dergisi**, **36**(1):49 – 54."

Here is the my .bst code:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f{.}.~}{vv~}{ll}{ jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                {

                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it in brute-force way. I comment out `bbl.and`  and `space.word * t *`. Then created a new line with `"," * space.word * t`.

```
"," * space.word * t
%bbl.and
%space.word * t *
```

I also changed the below lines.

```
numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
```

to

```
numnames #2 >
                { "" * }
                'skip$
```

Here is the full code:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              numnames #2 >
                { "" * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  "," * space.word * t 
                  %bbl.and
                  %space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f{.}.~}{vv~}{ll}{ jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              numnames #2 >
                { "" * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                {

                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  "," * space.word * t
                  %bbl.and
                  %space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```